# Fabric Composer Syntax Highlighter - prequisites doc reference is invalid

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In Development Pre-requisites [here](https://fabric-composer.github.io/tasks/prerequisites.html) it is recommended to use 'Atom Concerto Syntax Highlighter'. To my regret I can't see it among available packages. At https://atom.io/packages it`s absent  too.

Could somebody help me to install Atom Fabric Composer Syntax Highlighter?

Igar Lasica

Comment: This hasn't made it into the open GitHub repo yet - but is in progress. Please see the story raised for this https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

We just moved our experimental syntax highlighter for Atom into Open Source. It is here and includes install instructions:
https://github.com/fabric-composer/tools/tree/master/composer-atom-develop

We welcome contributions to make this more useful.

We are also working on publishing a more full-featured VSCode plugin which should be available shortly.